# intersystems cache - Is there a way to get change notivication on globals?

Tags: c#, intersystems-cache

I need realtime notifications on globals.

Because of the large amount of data it is very slow to read every time again and again the global data to detect what is change, delete or added.

For reading the globals i use the GlobalsFramework.dll and InterSystems.CacheExtreme.dll.

So i need tracking Data Changes without Audit Log.

Answer (score 0):

No way, no real-time notifications. The only way to get this information is from Journal files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer


How do I access the jounal in c #?
Can you give me an example of how I can read this.
There is so little information about this.

Comment: I'm not sure about C#, at least it should be available from ObjectScript. Look here https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25SYS.Journal.File